# Ionic storing multiple photos

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

Hi I have a problem with storing multiple photos. So basically it select photo from the phone gallery and it works fine till there. But when I want to select another photo it replaces the previous one.

```
getImages() {
    this.photos = [];
    const options: CameraOptions = {
      quality: 100,
      destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
      encodingType: this.camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
      mediaType: this.camera.MediaType.PICTURE,
      sourceType: this.camera.PictureSourceType.SAVEDPHOTOALBUM
    };

    this.camera.getPicture(options).then(
      imageData => {
        const base64Image = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;
        const imageName = `image_${this.subject.id}` + ".";
        const component = { imageName, base64Image, type: "image" };
        this.photos.push(component);
        this.photos.reverse();
        this.saveState();
      },
      err => {
        console.log(err);
      }
    );
  }

<ion-row *ngFor="let photo of photos; index as i" nowrap>
    <ion-icon class="subject-body-icon" name="camera" (click)="previewImage(photo)"></ion-icon>
    <span (click)="previewImage(photo)">{{ photo.imageName }}</span>
  </ion-row>
</div>

  <button class="disable-hover transparent-button" ion-button icon-only (click)="getImages()">
    <ion-icon name="cloud-upload"></ion-icon>
  </button>
```

Comment: `this.photos = [];` in your `getImages()` is the Problem. Everytime you call this function it will reinitialize your array. remove it from there.

Answer (score 3):

You init the photos-array in first line of your getImages-method (this.photos = []), this clears the array. Try to init the array in a ionic event like

```
ionViewDidEnter() {
    this.photos = []
  }
```

after loading the page!

See also here: https://ionicframework.com/docs/angular/lifecycle

Comment: does not work. as soon I click on getImages() button it removes old one and replace with new selected image

Comment: you can also init the array in component like:

 export class photoSelect {
  photos = [ ];

constructor() {
   photos = [ ];  // better here

}
....